# SQL server query to Calculate SUM of Child values in a Parent Child Table. Exclude Child's value from the sum if the parent has a value assigned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Pools where I need to show sum of child to each parent. If the grandchild's parent has a value than exclude grandchild's value from the sum

Table script and data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pools](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [Pool] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ParentPool] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Amount] [int] NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[Pools] ([id], [Pool], [ParentPool], [Amount]) VALUES (1, N'ROOT', NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pools] ([id], [Pool], [ParentPool], [Amount]) VALUES (2, N'Pool 1', N'ROOT', 10000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pools] ([id], [Pool], [ParentPool], [Amount]) VALUES (3, N'Pool 1.1', N'Pool 1', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pools] ([id], [Pool], [ParentPool], [Amount]) VALUES (4, N'Pool 1.2', N'Pool 1', 2000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pools] ([id], [Pool], [ParentPool], [Amount]) VALUES (5, N'Pool 1.3', N'Pool 1', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pools] ([id], [Pool], [ParentPool], [Amount]) VALUES (6, N'Pool 1.3.1', N'Pool 1.3', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pools] ([id], [Pool], [ParentPool], [Amount]) VALUES (7, N'Pool 1.3.2', N'Pool 1.3', 500)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pools] ([id], [Pool], [ParentPool], [Amount]) VALUES (8, N'Pool 1.3.3', N'Pool 1.3', 5000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pools] ([id], [Pool], [ParentPool], [Amount]) VALUES (9, N'Pool 2', N'ROOT', 35000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pools] ([id], [Pool], [ParentPool], [Amount]) VALUES (10, N'Pool 2.1', N'Pool 2', 28000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pools] ([id], [Pool], [ParentPool], [Amount]) VALUES (11, N'Pool 3', N'ROOT', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Pools] ([id], [Pool], [ParentPool], [Amount]) VALUES (12, N'Pool 3.1', N'Pool 3', 4500)
GO
```

Way I tried

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT pool, ParentPool, isnull(Amount,0.0)Amount
    FROM Pools
    WHERE ParentPool IS NULL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Pool, t.ParentPool, isnull(t.Amount,0.0)Amount
    FROM Pools t
    INNER JOIN CTE r ON t.ParentPool = r.pool
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Pools t2
        WHERE t2.Pool = t.ParentPool
        AND isnull(t2.Amount,0.0) > isnull(r.Amount,0.0) 

    )
)

SELECT Pool, ParentPool, isnull(Amount,0.0)Amount, (
        SELECT SUM(isnull(Amount,0.0))
        FROM CTE
        WHERE Pool IN (
            SELECT Pool
            FROM CTE
            WHERE ParentPool = t.Pool 
        )
    ) AS CalculatedAmount
FROM CTE t
```

Expected output

| Pool Name | Amount | Calculated amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ROOT |  | 49500 |
| Pool 1 | 10000 | 5000 |
| Pool 1.1 |  | 0 |
| Pool 1.2 | 2000 | 0 |
| Pool 1.3 | 3000 | 5500 |
| Pool 1.3.1 |  | 0 |
| Pool 1.3.2 | 500 | 0 |
| Pool 1.3.3 | 5000 | 0 |
| Pool 2 | 35000 | 28000 |
| Pool 2.1 | 28000 | 0 |
| Pool 3 |  | 4500 |
| Pool 3.1 | 4500 | 0 |

Image illustration

[Image illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHBsx.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `with c as(select *,Pool as cPool,Amount as cAmount, case when Amount is not null then 1 else 0 end as stopc,0 as pAmount,1 as plvl from dbo.Pools union all select c.id,c.Pool,c.ParentPool,c.Amount,p.Pool,case when c.stopc=1 then 0 else p.Amount end,case when c.stopc=1 or p.Amount is not null then 1 else 0 end
,case when c.plvl=1 then p.Amount end, c.plvl+case when p.Amount is null then 0 else 1 end
from c join dbo.Pools as p on c.cPool=p.ParentPool)
select id,Pool,ParentPool,Amount,case when Amount is null then sum(cAmount) else sum(pAmount) end
from c group by id,Pool,ParentPool,Amount;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @lptr:

Use a recursive CTE

```sql
with c as (
    select *,
      Pool as cPool,
      Amount as cAmount,
      case when Amount is not null then 1 else 0 end as stopc,
      0 as pAmount,
      1 as plvl
    from dbo.Pools

    union all

    select
      c.id,
      c.Pool,
      c.ParentPool,
      c.Amount,
      p.Pool,
      case when c.stopc = 1 then 0 else p.Amount end,
      case when c.stopc = 1 or p.Amount is not null then 1 else 0 end,
      case when c.plvl = 1 then p.Amount end,
      c.plvl + case when p.Amount is null then 0 else 1 end
    from c
    join dbo.Pools as p on c.cPool = p.ParentPool
)
select
  id,
  Pool,
  ParentPool,
  Amount,
  case when Amount is null then sum(cAmount) else sum(pAmount) end
from c
group by
  id,
  Pool,
  ParentPool,
  Amount;
```